# Do I need to install DirectX SDK if using windows 8 and above?

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, directx

I read this [topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx) but somehow it still doesn't get through my thick skull.
The topic said:

> Starting with Windows 8, the DirectX SDK is included as part of the
> Windows SDK.

So I try to find in this page a way to setup a directX project. I read:

> Using DirectX SDK projects with Visual Studio
>
> ...
>
> 1. Ensure that the June 2010 release of the DirectX SDK is installed on your development computer.

I don't understand what's this topic talking about. The first part it said in Windows 8, I don't have to install DirectX SDK (because it is included in Windows SDK), the part about HowTo setup directX project, it said I have to install DirectX SDK.

Anyway, I just ignore and keep going - I don't install DirectX SDK assuming it is already included in Windows SDK as the first quote states.
I do one thing as the topic said:

> Include Directories: $(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
>
> Include Library Directories: $(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86

In VS2015 **VC++ Directories** doesn't have **Include Library Directories:** so I understand it as **Library Directories**, the project is for win32 so I don't setup directX SDK for 64. Then I run the project and get the error:

```
TRK0005 Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So the question is: Do I need to install DirectX SDK if using windows 8 and above or I have to download and install [DirectX SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812)

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk/, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/,

Comment: Which version of DirectX are you planning to use? Are you planning to use D3DX (Direct3D extension)?

Comment: @Asesh I want to use the latest DirectX. But as they said, the last DirectX release is June 2010.

Comment: You don't need DirectX SDK (June 2010) if you don't plan to use old Direct3D extensions

Comment: BTW cl.exe is Visual C++ compiler so it has nothing to do with DirectX SDK

Comment: @Asesh: I found in VS2015 installer has: "Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 tools", maybe I need to install this.
about the error cl.exe, If I install DirectX SDK (June 2010), and link to that like this tutorial: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut01.html, then the error cl.exe solved.

Comment: Looks like those samples use Direct3D extensions, like I said to use Direct3D extension, you will have to install DirectX SDK. DirectX SDK which is included as part of Windows SDK doesn't support Direct3D extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and in more detail in this series of blog posts: [Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/), [The Zombie DirectX SDK](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/03/23/the-zombie-directx-sdk/), [DirectX SDKs of a certain age](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/08/21/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/), and [A Brief History of Windows SDKs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/10/03/a-brief-history-of-windows-sdks/).

- If you are coding a DirectX 11 application, you can use the Windows 8.1 SDK that comes with VS 2015 and don't need the DirectX SDK at all. This application can be written to run on Windows Vista SP2 or later. You don't need the DirectSetup REDIST either as deployment is part of the [OS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416644(v=VS.85).aspx). Do not make use of `D3DX11` and use one of the many open source [replacements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) instead. If you are writing a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, you *can't* use the legacy DirectX SDK as those components won't pass WACK.

> If you are new to DirectX 11, a good place to start is the [Direct3D VS Game Templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/releases) and the [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11 tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

- The one case where you might need the legacy DirectX SDK for your DirectX 11 app is if you want to use XAudio2 on Windows 7. This is covered [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8/). If you require Windows 8 or Windows 10 to run, you can just use XAudio2 that's built into the OS and the Windows SDK.

> This requires 'mixing' the Windows 8.1 SDK with the legacy DirectX SDK include paths which is where all the guideance about switching the include/lib path order comes from. For a Windows desktop app, you can still use legacy `D3DX` if you want with VS 2015--such as when using outdated tutorials or [books](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) to learn from--but note that the DXERR library is not compatible with the Visual C++ 2015 REDIST. You can work around this issue per [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/24/wheres-dxerr-lib/).

- If you are coding a legacy DirectX 9 application, then you likely want to support Windows XP as well. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1/) for details on how this works with VS 2015, and this does require the legacy DirectX SDK.
- There's nothing in the legacy DirectX SDK for DirectX 12.

> For information on other aspects of the moving beyond the legacy DirectX SDK see [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), [DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog/), [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/), [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/), and [Not So Direct Setup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/)

If you are looking to use DirectX with C# instead of C++, be sure to read [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/12/09/directx-and-net/).